# mod_pagespeed client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.4, mod-pagespeed

I'm unable to find a solution for this problem and I already read all the relevant topics on here. I understand this is some problem with the Require directive in some Directory. But I don't have any "Require all denied" except for /, /var/www has "Require all granted". I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the file doesn't really exists on disk, but I don't know how to fix it.

This only happens if I activate the rewrite_images or compress_images filter in mod_pagespeed (ver. 1.11.33.2-r0).

The error happens with img tags for example this:

```
<img src="/img/cms/img.png" alt="img" width="330" height="145" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);">
```

Translates into this:

```
<img src="/img/cms/ximg.png.pagespeed.ic.7r3fOhvSE_.webp" alt="img" width="330" height="145" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);" data-pagespeed-url-hash="885240078" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);">
```

and throws this error in apache logs:

```
[Tue Jul 26 15:03:00.609926 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 8116:tid 140318443788032] [client x.x.x.x:46972] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: uri /img/cms/ximg.png.pagespeed.ic.7r3fOhvSE_.webp, referer: https://www.example.com/
```

And a 403 in browser console.

I also tried to enable debug which show nothing more.

apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

vhost.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin info@example.com
                ServerName www.example.com
                ServerAlias example.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/example/
                LogLevel info ssl:warn
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl.error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl.access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mycert.key
                SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.cer
                <IfModule setenvif_module>
                        SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
                </IfModule>
                <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$">
                        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/mysite-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
                </FilesMatch>
                <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
                        Require all denied
                </FilesMatch>
                <FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml|ps)$">
                        Require all denied
                </FilesMatch>
                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: OK. I noticed a weird thing. It happens only with files that start with 'x'. And since all the pagespeed rewrites rename the file with x+something they throw the error. Still I can't find why any file with x should be forbidden by my conf.

Comment: One hint is that it's access_compat (Order/Deny)and not authz_core (Require). Did you check htaccess?

Comment: There isn't any allow/deny in htaccess (or require). There is only a rewrite:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]`